# How can i insert this array into the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How i will make a this array value converted into a string for enable me to insert it to the database.

```
$myArray = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Ohtels Villa Dorada
                )

            [description] => Array
                (
                    [content] => This hotel is located about 150 metres from the fine sandy beach. The lively centre of Cambrils is approximately 10 km away and can be easily reached by the public bus services. There is a stop for public transport right in front of the hotel. The immediate vicinity offers a diverse range of shopping and entertainment facilities including boutiques, restaurants and bars. This hotel comprises a total of 260 rooms spread over 5 floors. Dining options include a café, a bar and an air-conditioned buffet restaurant with highchairs for infants. The tastefully decorated, cosy rooms come with a balcony and satellite TV.
                )

            [countryCode] => ES
            [stateCode] => 43
            [destinationCode] => SAL
            [zoneCode] => 10
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [longitude] => 1.152529
                    [latitude] => 41.068407
                )

            [categoryCode] => 3EST
            [categoryGroupCode] => GRUPO3
            [chainCode] => OHTEL
            [accommodationTypeCode] => HOTEL
            [boardCodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => BB
                    [1] => AI
                    [2] => HB
                    [3] => FB
                    [4] => RO
                )

            [segmentCodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 37
                )

            [address] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Carrer Del Vendrell,11  
                )

            [postalCode] => 43840
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [content] => SALOU
                )

            [email] => comercial@ohtels.es
            [license] => HT-000473
            [web] => http://www.ohtels.es/
            [lastUpdate] => 2019-03-14
            [S2C] => 4*
            [ranking] => 96
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Sample
                )

            [description] => Array
                (
                    [content] => This hotel is located about 150 metres from the fine sandy beach. The lively centre of Cambrils is approximately 10 km away and can be easily reached by the public bus services. There is a stop for public transport right in front of the hotel. The immediate vicinity offers a diverse range of shopping and entertainment facilities including boutiques, restaurants and bars. This hotel comprises a total of 260 rooms spread over 5 floors. Dining options include a café, a bar and an air-conditioned buffet restaurant with highchairs for infants. The tastefully decorated, cosy rooms come with a balcony and satellite TV.
                )

            [countryCode] => ES
            [stateCode] => 43
            [destinationCode] => SAL
            [zoneCode] => 10
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [longitude] => 1.152529
                    [latitude] => 41.068407
                )

            [categoryCode] => 3EST
            [categoryGroupCode] => GRUPO3
            [chainCode] => OHTEL
            [accommodationTypeCode] => HOTEL
            [boardCodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => BB
                    [1] => AI
                    [2] => HB
                    [3] => FB
                    [4] => RO
                )

            [segmentCodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 37
                )

            [address] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Carrer Del Vendrell,11  
                )

            [postalCode] => 43840
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [content] => SALOU
                )

            [email] => comercial@ohtels.es
            [license] => HT-000473
            [web] => http://www.ohtels.es/
            [lastUpdate] => 2019-03-14
            [S2C] => 4*
            [ranking] => 96
        )
)
```

i want all of the value of the `$myArray` would be inserted to the database

But also i used `foreach` loop to store it to a `$variable` and i will just concatinate the value into the query.

```
INSERT INTO test(code,contents) VALUES $variable;
```

Here is what am i doing.

```
$hotel_content = '';
foreach($myArray as $content)
{
  $hotel_content  .= "(".$content['code'].",".json_encode($content)."),";
}

$hotel = "INSERT INTO test(code,contents) VALUES ".rtrim($hotel_content,",").';';

if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $hotel) ) 
{
    echo "You have successfully inserted the data.";
} 
else 
{
  echo "Error: " . $hotel . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: What is your table structure ? I doubt you want to store the whole array serialized into your DB, that would goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS

Comment: `json_encode` would convert that into a string. Depending upon version of mySQL you might even have a `JSON` column type available - either way it would be a string and can be stored

Comment: when i used the json_encode() the result is wrap with the curly brace thats why if i concatinate it to the values i received an error about that curly braces as also the same with serialize . i think the mysql didnt accept the curly brace?

Comment: Wait i will be edit my post. For more info.

Comment: @MiksAlibo your query **must** be parameterized, otherwise it will certainly result a MySQL error

Comment: How would i do that? I post my workflow on how to insert it to the database.

Comment: @MiksAlibo reading [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) will be a good start

Answer (score 1):

**Way 1:** 
You can insert full array by converting it to `sting`. So you can use PHP `serialize` function before insert.

```
$serialized_data = serialize($myarray);
```

then user `$serialized_data` into your insert query. 
Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

**Note** you've to unserialize it when you'll use this data. So after retrieving from database unserialize it by `unserialize()` function.

**Another way:** you can use `json_encode()` function to store `array`. and you'll also need to use `json_decode()` when/where you'll use this data.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I do this also . but the curly brace inside that string is not accepted i think by mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Define table column as longText
 like this

```
 $table->longText('column_name');
```

Then save data into it as JSON STRING

```
$value = json_encode($myArray);
```